# How to target only webkit-based browsers in a print stylesheet?

Tags: css, printing, webkit

I'm facing some layout issues with a print stylesheet in webkit-based browsers, and I was wondering if there was a CSS selector, or another way to do a CSS hack to only target webkit / media print?

The classical webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio media query selector isn't working for printing.

So what's the printing equivalent to this CSS Hack? (changing the media to print, isn't working):

`@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {`

}

Comment: Tricks like this are not recommended at all. Can't you fix the print stylesheet to work in all browsers? What exactly breaks? Maybe we can help with that.

Comment: There's not wrong with this. A good example of use might be "People who use Safari favor ease of use, while UI users want a simple to understand and familiar UI, while Firefox users want something more advanced due to their higher than average technical aptitude." This would allow you to cater your site to target sub-audiences of the greater population.

Comment: I always get pissed when people try to feed me different content just because I happen to use some browser. I guess it's just me.

Comment: @Rodin I know it's not recommended, and want in general to avoid using CSS hacks, but in this case it's needed. The issue is a separate question...

Answer (score 5):

You could use javascript to load CSS files for WebKit browsers only.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" id="hacks"/>
    <script>
        if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("WebKit") != -1) {
            document.getElementById("hacks").href="hacks.css";
        }
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Plus it seems less like a hack

Answer (score 3):

You could include a stylesheet that will only be used for webkit browsers like so:

```
@media print and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    .black {
        color:black;
    }
}
```

There are similar features in other browsers.

Comment: This is picked up by older versions of Opera.

Comment: @Knu Opera?! But, it says `-webkit-`... Opera did that? Do you know on which version?

Comment: @Knu Well, then I guess it's safe to assume the number of users affected by that would be way below 1% globally.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. Failing for me on Chromium v71.0.3578.98

Answer (score 1):

Use `webkit-any-link` instead:

```
@media print 
  {
  * > /**/ #foo, x:-webkit-any-link { padding-top: 200px; }
  }
```

The `* > /**/` selector is used to filter IE7, and can be removed if it's unsupported:

```
@media print 
  {
  #foo, x:-webkit-any-link { padding-top: 200px; }
  }
```

**References**

- [Issues for Level 4 [CSS Working Group Wiki]](https://wiki.csswg.org/spec/selectors)
- [CSS Selectors Level 4: The Path to CSS4](http://www.sitepoint.com/css-selectors-level-4-the-path-to-css4/)
- [Reveal New Window Links and Links to Non HTML Files with a User Stylesheet](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200812/reveal_new_window_links_and_links_to_non-html_files_with_a_user_stylesheet/)